# Best online backup provider with simple and secure FTP server

Tags: backup, hosting, ftp, rsync

I'm looking to do online backups of some data from a Linux server. The amount of data is pretty small right now and it's unlikely to ever exceed 10 GB or so. I've already got a cron job set up that compresses and encrypts the data and uploads it to an FTP server - all I need is the FTP server. I'm looking for something reliable, secure and not-ridiculously-expensive. Ideally I don't want to install any third-party software, but just use FTP or scp. If the server is in Europe that would be a plus.

I've read a few similar questions that suggest, Mozy, Dropbox, Backblaze, etc., but these all require their own software, which does fancy stuff that I don't need. I just need the FTP space. What do you recommend, preferably from experience?

Answer (score 4):

Worth noting that FTP is inherently insecure due to it's habit of passing passwords across the network in plain text. You may not be able to avoid using it but if can do so!

If possible use [SCP/SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy).

Provider wise, I have used [BqBackup](http://www.bqbackup.com/) for a number of years without issue, they provide you with a Unix shell on one of their BSD servers so you can transfer via FTP,SCP,RSYNC, etc.

Answer (score 3):

My gut reaction would be to buy a hosted domain and just use it for an FTP repository.

Comment: That was my gut reaction, too, but most web hosts disallow that. They say that you are only allowed to store files used by your website (ie. the one you're hosting with them).

Answer (score 2):

I'd try [rsync.net (FAQ Page)](http://www.rsync.net/resources/faq.html). They offer quite a bunch of nice features including geo redundant storage.

Not quite as cheap as Amazon S3 but personally I do like their feature set a lot more. One reason is that you do have a basic SSH account available, another is rsync and a third is there is no file size limit with rsync.net as opposed to Amazon S3 which limits to a maximum file size of 5GB

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently experimenting with using [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) for backups. You can pay by the GB, there are servers in Europe and the USA, and you can use various ways of accessing your 'buckets', including REST and SOAP protocols. I'm not sure exactly what you need for uploading, but I am planning on using a tool called [jets3t](https://jets3t.dev.java.net/) which includes an rsync-alike with encryption. Does need Java though.

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of **Site5** accounts just for backup.  They are really cheap and offer ssh access, which means you can use things like rsync over ssh as well and the standard protocols.

I've found their service to be good enough.  I would rely on them 100% for my business, but as an easy offsite backup, they've worked well.  Of course, any hosted provider would work just as well and they are currently offering lots of space for cheap.

Comment: It looked promising, but I asked them and they don't allow their service to be used for file storage - just like pretty much every other web host.

Answer (score 1):

What about iFolder?

Answer (score 1):

I use an [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/) account for backups.  I haven't tried to FTP stuff there but apparently it [can be done](http://www.crossftp.com/).

S3 is cheap as heck and damn reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Ibackup](https://www.ibackup.com/) is available for Windows and Mac platforms, as well support rsync for Linux. Their list of features is impressive. I am going to evaluate their solution.

Answer (score 0):

The folks over at http://www.backupmyinfo.com/ offer really competitive and personal services with dedicated engineers and account reps for the life of each account.  I've worked with them and I highly recommend.  Mention Nick O'Neil for a discount :)

Answer (score 0):

If your backup needs will stay under 50 GB, then hosting at http://dreamhost.com/ would work for you. They explicitly allow a backup user as long as you stay under that. They also have SFTP, which is a more secure option than straight FTP.